# Does google drive SDK ios api allow proxy setting

Tags: objective-c, ios6, google-drive-api

Does google drive SDK ios api support proxy setting? Currently I am using goodle drive sdk in my own ios application and I would like to know that is there anyway for me to set up proxy setting in the code or will the google drive will automatically add the proxy setting in the request?

Answer (score 1):

`google-api-objectivec-client` doesn't support proxying at the moment. If you're not planning to use the client library, you can't proxify the requests.

Comment: Thanks for the response, you mention that if not planning to user the client library, I can't proxify the requests, google-api-objective-client and the client library are not the same thing?

Comment: If you're not planning to use the client library, you can't proxify the requests. Could you teach me how to do so if I use the client library, which client library should I use?

Comment: @Burcu Dogan,  Mam, is it possible to get public url of google drive, which can be used to play from browser